# Any java API for Latitude and Longitude in Java

Tags: java, api, latitude-longitude

I m looking for a Java API which can help me find the city/country with a given latitude and longitude ?

Comment: this link might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256091/getting-city-name-and-country-name-by-longitude-and-latitude

Answer (score 2):

This API endpoint below should do this for you.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

you can specify the format either as XML or JSON, then parse with either a JSON parser (GSON, Jackson etc) or an XML parser (SAX, DOM...)